# Set Icon with binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Mahapps Metro and Mahapps IconPack.

```
xmlns:icons="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
```

I have a `Itemscontrols` what works as expected, like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <icons:MaterialDesign Kind="Home"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now I want to set the `Icon` from the `collection` for each `item`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <icons:MaterialDesign Kind="{Binding icon}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have a property which will be added to the collection:

```
public MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconMaterialKind MyIcon = MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconMaterialKind.AbTesting;
```

If I do so I will get the following error:

> Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

I tried to setup the `DependencyObject` like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIcon =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyIcon), typeof(MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconMaterialKind), typeof(MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconMaterialKind), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconMaterialKind myIcon
{
    get { return (MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconMaterialKind)GetValue(dependencyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(dependencyProperty, value); }
}
```

But the `GetValue` and `SetValue` are not recognised.

I also tried to set this through a `style`, but then only the `string` to the `icon` will be set as `content` and not the `icon` itself.

Can anybody please explain me where I got lost, and how to do this.

Thank you very much.

---

Thanks for the comments. I was able to figure it out.

I added:

```
public PackIconMaterialDesign IconMaterialDesign => new PackIconMaterialDesign { Kind = PackIconMaterialDesignKind.AccessAlarm, Height = 30, Width = 30 };
```

And then I was able to bind it:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ViewModelRouter}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ViewModelName}"
        Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
        Content="{Binding IconMaterialDesign}" >
```

Comment: `Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`. Means that you can't bind `{ Binding }` to a property that isn't set up for it. From the code you've shown, the likely culprit is `<icons:MaterialDesign Kind="{Binding icon}"/>`, meaning you can't use a binding for property `Kind` on type `MaterialDesign`. Where did `icons:MaterialDesign` come from? I don't see this in Mahapps Metro docs.

Comment: I added the information. It´s the IconPack

Comment: put `MaterialDesign` objects into collection and bing `Button Content={Binding icon}` Where icon will  be `MaterialDesign`.

Comment: You should operate not with `PackIconMaterialKind` but with `MaterialDesign` objects. You can't bind it because `MaterialDesign` object is no at dependency object.

Comment: Alternatively you can write converter (derive it from IValueConverter) which will create Material design objects from PackIconMaterialKind and use it <Button Content={Binding icon, Converter={StaticResource materialConverter}}

Comment: Have you tried `<icons:PackIconMaterial Kind="{Binding icon}"/>` According to the code, Kind is a binding property: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/blob/8f0c19f7999f001885ca9944457ac1688813ccab/src/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/PackIconMaterial.cs. We are also working of the assumption that `icon` is a string property on your types in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I was able to figure it out.

I added:

```
public PackIconMaterialDesign IconMaterialDesign => 
new PackIconMaterialDesign { Kind = 
PackIconMaterialDesignKind.AccessAlarm, Height = 30, 
Width = 30 };
```

And then i was able to bind it:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding ViewModelRouter}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ViewModelName}"
    Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
    Content="{Binding IconMaterialDesign}" >
```